# Xcode: CodeSign failed and unable to run app

Tags: xcode

I am going to run a flutter app on simulator, but Xcode gives a "CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code" error. 
The Xcode Version is 10.2.1

I have set the "Signing" to iphone Developer, but still not able to solve.

I followed other instructs on stack overflow to change build settings, certificates in key access and "xattr -cr file_path" but still not help the issue.

**Supporting Images**
https://prnt.sc/nrujwm
https://prnt.sc/nruk92

---

Signing Identity:     "-"
"Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code"

Comment: You can do some steps for troubleshooting. Currently, you are using automatic code signing. Go to your General tab of product and check you are providing correct bundle id. somehow like this com.yourcompanyname.yourbundleid

Comment: by the way for simulator no code sign required.